# kafka error: Request for offset X but we only have log segments in the range Y to Z

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I had working kafka instance but now it produces thousands of errors that looks like:

> [2016-06-24 01:33:28,092] ERROR [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Error
>   when processing fetch request for partition [test-topic,0] offset 45
>   from consumer with correlation id 85452. Possible cause: Request for
>   offset 45 but we only have log segments in the range 0 to 0.
>   (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)

I'm using default configuration. I'm using several topics in node.js code.

**UPD:** reinstalling kafka helps me, but I'd like to know original source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please read here for the source of problem
https://github.com/endgameinc/elasticsearch-river-kafka/issues/8

You might have deleted some of the files or folders in kafka.